# Error Message after FTP backup

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, error

Can't access my page or **backend**.  Am getting the **following error**.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract' not found in
>   /homepages/39/d513863541/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php
>   on line 36

Please help as I'm completely boned at this point in time!

```
<?php

/**
 * Abstract resource model class
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Core
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
abstract class Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract
{
    /**
     * @deprecated since 1.5.0.0
     */
    const CHECKSUM_KEY_NAME= 'Checksum';

    /**
     * Cached resources singleton
     *
     * @var Mage_Core_Model_Resource
     */
    protected $_resources;

    /**
     * Prefix for resources that will be used in this resource model
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_resourcePrefix;

    /**
     * Connections cache for this resource model
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_connections          = array();

    /**
     * Resource model name that contains entities (names of tables)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_resourceModel;

    /**
     * Tables used in this resource model
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_tables               = array();

    /**
     * Main table name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_mainTable;

    /**
     * Main table primary key field name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName;

    /**
     * Primery key auto increment flag
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isPkAutoIncrement    = true;

    /**
     * Use is object new method for save of object
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $_useIsObjectNew       = false;

    /**
     * Fields List for update in forsedSave
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_fieldsForUpdate      = array();

    /**
     * Fields of main table
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_mainTableFields;

    /**
     * Main table unique keys field names
     * could array(
     *   array('field' => 'db_field_name1', 'title' => 'Field 1 should be unique')
     *   array('field' => 'db_field_name2', 'title' => 'Field 2 should be unique')
     *   array(
     *      'field' => array('db_field_name3', 'db_field_name3'),
     *      'title' => 'Field 3 and Field 4 combination should be unique'
     *   )
     * )
     * or string 'my_field_name' - will be autoconverted to
     *      array( array( 'field' => 'my_field_name', 'title' => 'my_field_name' ) )
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_uniqueFields         = null;

    /**
     * Serializable fields declaration
     * Structure: array(
     *     <field_name> => array(
     *         <default_value_for_serialization>,
     *         <default_for_unserialization>,
     *         <whether_to_unset_empty_when serializing> // optional parameter
     *     ),
     * )
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_serializableFields   = array();

    /**
     * Standard resource model initialization
     *
     * @param string $mainTable
     * @param string $idFieldName
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract
     */
    protected function _init($mainTable, $idFieldName)
    {
        $this->_setMainTable($mainTable, $idFieldName);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize connections and tables for this resource model
     * If one or both arguments are string, will be used as prefix
     * If $tables is null and $connections is string, $tables will be the same
     *
     * @param string|array $connections
     * @param string|array|null $tables
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract
     */
    protected function _setResource($connections, $tables = null)
    {
        $this->_resources = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

        if (is_array($connections)) {
            foreach ($connections as $k=>$v) {
                $this->_connections[$k] = $this->_resources->getConnection($v);
            }
        } else if (is_string($connections)) {
            $this->_resourcePrefix = $connections;
        }

        if (is_null($tables) && is_string($connections)) {
            $this->_resourceModel = $this->_resourcePrefix;
        } else if (is_array($tables)) {
            foreach ($tables as $k => $v) {
                $this->_tables[$k] = $this->_resources->getTableName($v);
            }
        } else if (is_string($tables)) {
            $this->_resourceModel = $tables;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any `Abstract` file in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/` directory ?

Comment: Ah ha!  That's the ticket.  That file is showing as 0 file size.  Threw up a backup copy and everything is starting to come back.  Many many thanks!!

Comment: Good news, I will answer that way that you can mark it as resolved and accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the comments, that error means that the file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Abstract.php` does not exist or is empty.